# Calling service timeouts after few calls

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, timeout

I am developing a WCFService (C#) which is a 'wrapper' for external webservice provided by external company. Connection between myService and exterService works like a charm on dev machine and on test server provided by my client - issues start on production server - when I upload my service and call it from website it works for few calls and than external service starts to throw timeouts - in my original code I used using directive, but after reading few similar problems threads I've changed it to use .Close on service Client. Unfortunately it did not helped. Could you try to help me?

This is the code that calls external Service.

```
public static ExternalResponse RunAskQuestionBasicQuery(ExternalRequest request, string innerTransId)
    {
        ExternalResponse resp = null;
        ExternalTestSoapClient client = new ExternalTestSoapClient("ExternalTestSoap12");

        Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient created.");
        try
        {
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "AskQuestion() calling...");
            resp = client.AskQuestion(request.SearchNumber, User, Password);
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "AskQuestion() called.");
            client.Close();
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient closed.");
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            client.Abort();
            resp = null;
            SetError(bvResp, "External service is not accessible.");
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient aborted [CommunicationException].");
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            client.Abort();
            resp = null;
            SetError(bvResp, "External service is not accessible.");
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient aborted [TimeoutException].");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
 }
```

And after some calls I just start getting timeouts.

Comment: It might be helpful to see what the message of the exception is and any inner exception details.

Comment: Are dev/test using a different endpoint for the external service than the production environment? If it is different then this suggests there is a problem with the external service in the production environment and you need to contact the provider.

Comment: Timeouts after a few calls makes me think connections are not being closed and you are hitting maxConcurrentSessions (default 10 I think). Do you get 'ExternalTestSoapClient closed' logged successfully?

Comment: @ShellShock - unfortunately it is exactly the same endpoint.

Comment: @ajg - we do log 'ExternalTestSoapClient closed' successfully. And it's not 10 calls - sometimes it's 12, sometimes it's 14, today morning it was over 20. We added logging of .State of client after calling .Close() - and it seems to start working. I will have to wait till afternoon when server load is higher - maybe than it will start failing again - I am getting more and more confused. If it will start failing afternoon - I will paste logs.

Comment: When the external service times out, how long has that call taken? You could try increasing the sendTimeout on the external service binding in your proxy's config.

Answer (score 0):

I cant really see anything wrong with your code, one small thing though it shouldn't matter as you make a new client each time but I'm not sure I'd have a static method calling a WCF service.

I've had the most luck with WCF using this pattern - its very close to yours just moving the Close() into a finally block

```
public ExternalResponse RunAskQuestionBasicQuery(ExternalRequest request, string innerTransId)
{
    ExternalResponse resp = null;
    ExternalTestSoapClient client = new ExternalTestSoapClient("ExternalTestSoap12");

    Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient created.");
    try
    {
        Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "AskQuestion() calling...");
        resp = client.AskQuestion(request.SearchNumber, User, Password);
        Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "AskQuestion() called.");           
        return resp;
    }
    catch (CommunicationException)
    {
        client.Abort();
        resp = null;
        SetError(bvResp, "External service is not accessible.");
        Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient aborted [CommunicationException].");
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        client.Abort();
        resp = null;
        SetError(bvResp, "External service is not accessible.");
        Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient aborted [TimeoutException].");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
            client.Close();
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(innerTransId, "ExternalTestSoapClient closed.");
        }
    }
}
```